# from_avro giving nulls as output while reading Kafka AVRO binary values

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, databricks

I am using databricks (Spark 3.2) to read Kafka messages which are in avro format.

I am using from_avro referring the spark [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.avro.functions.from_avro.html)

```
from pyspark.sql.avro.functions import from_avro, to_avro
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json, col
from pyspark.sql.types import MapType,StringType

jsonFormatSchema=   '''{
    "type": "record",
    "name": "TransactionEvent",
    "fields": [{"name":"status","type":"string","default":null}]
        
    }
'''
from_avro_options= {"mode":"PERMISSIVE"}


df = spark.read.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:9092,host2:9092:9092,host3:9092:9092").option("subscribe", "topic_name").load()
output = df.select(col("value").cast("string"))

output=df.select(from_avro("value",jsonFormatSchema,from_avro_options)).collect()
print(output[0])
```

**Output**

```
Row(from_avro(value)=Row(status=None))
```

I have seen someone have reported it [as a bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-32834) as well.

Comment: do you see any error when you change the mode to `FAILFAST`?

Comment: yes, it was failing on few stages. In the error itself it was mentioned to use FAILFAST. @SaiKiranKrishnaMurthy

Comment: maybe you can update the question with the error logs, it looks like there is a mismatch between the schema and the data

Comment: but i don't see any error when i run the above code in permissive mode, it just get NULL values for the column. I don't think that it can be a schema problem because i have just taken a single column and that too is checked with already present schema.

Comment: going by the documentation:

`PERMISSIVE: Corrupt records are processed as null result. Therefore, the data schema is forced to be fully nullable, which might be different from the one user provided.`

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-avro.html#to_avro-and-from_avro